# How to write a Dart 'worker' server

Tags: dart, dart-io

I want to write a Dart server that reads from a Firebase queue and sends emails.

What is not clear to me is how to write a server that listens for something other than HTTP requests, in my case a Firebase queue like e.g. [this project](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-work-queue) .

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but it seems this repo should provide all you need https://github.com/igrigorik/heroku-buildpack-dart

Comment: Thanks Gunter. I have edited the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

It does not "listen" to HTTP connections in the original client <-> server sense. It takes a job from the queue and executes it, then returns back the result and goes on with the next job.

You'd need a Dart wrapper for the Firebase queue implementation.